# Create a in-browser Python application with a GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, browser

I am teaching a class soon and I want to have users try my platform without the need of installing Python in their computers and to run everything online. I have searched for platforms such as Skulpt, CodeMirror and Trinket and they seem ok for what I want to do. However, I want to develop a GUI for the users to input parameters since there are a lot of options and I don't want users with no Python experience to run the programs from the command line like I do and hide the Python code behind the GUI. I have learnt simplegui recently but I think the GUIs you can create are not visually pleasant and for me this is a big no. I also saw in another post that using Tkinker with a in-browser python implementation is not possible.

So, I would like to know what would be the best combination of in-browser Python implementation and GUI module to reach my goal please?

Thank you so much!

Comment: not sure if this is what you are looking for, but I've had luck with bottle to make web-based python applications

Comment: Thank you! I have to study a lot of web development, wow! I have been reading the documentation and I'm afraid it won't work because of the yield statements. Simpy is the core library of my project and it seems that the yield statements in bottle do not support yielding timeouts like in simpy, but I have to test it.

Comment: have you looked at [Brython](https://www.brython.info/)?

Comment: Seems fine, I'll study Brython better. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess [Jupyter](http://jupyter.org/) could meet your needs. [Getting started here](http://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html).

> The Jupyter Notebook is a web application that allows you to create and share documents that contain live code, equations, visualizations and explanatory text. Uses include: data cleaning and transformation, numerical simulation, statistical modeling, machine learning and much more.
>
> The Notebook has support for over 40 programming languages, including those popular in Data Science such as Python, R, Julia and Scala.

Comment: Thank you! I already use Jupyter but it requires that I have Python installed already in the machines probably? I use Jupyter with the Anaconda Python implementation often. If there is a way that I can show a Jupyter link instead of the .ipynb file  without having the users needing to install Python in their computers would be ideal.

Comment: @CatiaB.  Hi, I haven't verify whether Jupyter Notebook works well on a client host without python installed (since most people around me are using *nix system). But I think philosophy of Jupyter is just encapsulating all these dependencies at server side to make browser side as light-weight as possible. I will find an environment to have a try tomorrow.

Comment: Updated: please refer the doc here, http://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/architecture/how_jupyter_ipython_work.html . Notebook server takes care your concern.